# Getting 403 when trying to download an image

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to download a few pictures from a website using Python. These are a couple of them:
https://www.innovasport.com/medias/IS-DB2455-728-1.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w3Mzg2MHxpbWFnZS9qcGVnfGltYWdlcy9oM2QvaDk5LzEwNTY3NzE3MDYwNjM4LmpwZ3wwYmJiZjA5MjZkZjNhZTQwMTZiYzdmNTVhM2RmZDhiMTY2ZjI2YzNkY2QzZmUwYmQxNzc5OTY2MTZlNGMxYzBi

https://www.innovasport.com/medias/playera-nike-jordan-jumpman-is-CJ0921-011-1.png?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1MDg4MnxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g3ZS9oMjgvOTc1OTk4MjY4MjE0Mi5wbmd8NTZlODA5YzhmMDZmOGMyYTBkODliMGM3NGE0NGE0YzBlOThhMTAzM2ZmMWMyODM4M2ZjNTVjNmNmZWExM2VkNw

When opening the picture URLs directly in my browser, they open without problems. But when using a simple Python script I keep getting a 403 error message. Is there a way to get past this error?

First I tried a simple requests.get like this:

```
tshirt_pic = requests.get("https://www.innovasport.com/medias/playera-nike-jordan-jumpman-is-CJ0921-011-1.png?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w1MDg4MnxpbWFnZS9wbmd8aW1hZ2VzL2g3ZS9oMjgvOTc1OTk4MjY4MjE0Mi5wbmd8NTZlODA5YzhmMDZmOGMyYTBkODliMGM3NGE0NGE0YzBlOThhMTAzM2ZmMWMyODM4M2ZjNTVjNmNmZWExM2VkNw").content
with open('my_pic.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(tshirt_pic)
```

But the only thing it downloaded was the error html.

Then, investigating a bit, I got suggestions of using the chrome developer Network options for getting the request cURL, translating it using https://curlconverter.com/ and finally use it for all picture requests from the site. But that didn't work either. I got the cURL, got it translated, and used it in my code, like this, but still go the 403 error.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.1635147955.1647278637',
    '_vwo_uuid_v2': 'D7C88F448C90BA0FDC79062506EA49315|3249aaf2b173d1e5e3eb349b745491dd',
    '_ALGOLIA': 'anonymous-cd27a5b3-6878-44ea-a8da-61284eefc793',
    '_bamls_usid': 'd7c79c9a-0c5d-4e6d-a8e0-8b35f9873454',
    '_vwo_uuid': 'D7C88F448C90BA0FDC79062506EA49315',
    'scarab.visitor': '%225627060B81890552%22',
    'mdLogger': 'false',
    'kampyle_userid': '7a7c-b559-ced5-cdfe-7a9f-1b46-f8f6-5992',
    'cd_user_id': '17f897547b459f-0ee040800429a-192b1e05-1fa400-17f897547b5b8e',
    '_hjSessionUser_2536688': 'eyJpZCI6IjVkNjlkMzMxLWNlMDAtNTVhMi04NWY3LTIyZDcwNjRmNjYwNyIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDcyNzg2Mzc5NjksImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==',
    'BVBRANDID': 'b448d567-f852-45f4-b114-784aa3f60b22',
    'scarab.profile': '%22000000000000210994%7C1647278780%22',
    '_gcl_aw': 'GCL.1647291885.Cj0KCQjwz7uRBhDRARIsAFqjulk5bAJN9VM34Mvu46mlftXA-pi6u3ihl_b1WF2cYYGRHiiBqQv-IlMaAiEIEALw_wcB',
    '_gac_UA-36216968-26': '1.1647291885.Cj0KCQjwz7uRBhDRARIsAFqjulk5bAJN9VM34Mvu46mlftXA-pi6u3ihl_b1WF2cYYGRHiiBqQv-IlMaAiEIEALw_wcB',
    '_gac_UA-36216968-1': '1.1647291892.Cj0KCQjwz7uRBhDRARIsAFqjulk5bAJN9VM34Mvu46mlftXA-pi6u3ihl_b1WF2cYYGRHiiBqQv-IlMaAiEIEALw_wcB',
    'DECLINED_DATE': '1647363860132',
    '_ga': 'GA1.1.1904468361.1647278637',
    '_vis_opt_s': '3%7C',
    'kampyleUserSession': '1647443910700',
    'kampyleUserSessionsCount': '12',
    'kampyleSessionPageCounter': '1',
    'kampyleUserPercentile': '76.69597099170795',
    '_vwo_ds': '3%3Aa_0%2Ct_0%3A0%241647278636%3A14.83535232%3A%3A65_0%2C62_0%3A443_0%2C431_0%2C430_0%2C427_0%2C5_0%2C4_0%3A0',
    '_ga_Z8VQ1XLMKW': 'GS1.1.1647482462.8.0.1647482462.60',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.1904468361.1647278637',
    '_clck': 'ocen0m|1|ezu|0',
    '_uetvid': '87e73510a3bb11ec845961db4a2ee8f4',
    '__cf_bm': 'Wq7Ri6TwjPflvuTcmaxx_NBGVkBBtewayXNGkF6iRFY-1650921677-0-AenKxR/rPecqs7Ap4M3KUrJz1uWOsVHq8XxTeffRjRC39318w5Y5p5s7+izyRnzL9CxSdTMCKZpgIg1sQoyaPxQ=',
    'cf_chl_2': 'a1a45f416d52eea',
    'cf_chl_prog': 'b',
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.1635147955.1647278637; _vwo_uuid_v2=D7C88F448C90BA0FDC79062506EA49315|3249aaf2b173d1e5e3eb349b745491dd; _ALGOLIA=anonymous-cd27a5b3-6878-44ea-a8da-61284eefc793; _bamls_usid=d7c79c9a-0c5d-4e6d-a8e0-8b35f9873454; _vwo_uuid=D7C88F448C90BA0FDC79062506EA49315; scarab.visitor=%225627060B81890552%22; mdLogger=false; kampyle_userid=7a7c-b559-ced5-cdfe-7a9f-1b46-f8f6-5992; cd_user_id=17f897547b459f-0ee040800429a-192b1e05-1fa400-17f897547b5b8e; _hjSessionUser_2536688=eyJpZCI6IjVkNjlkMzMxLWNlMDAtNTVhMi04NWY3LTIyZDcwNjRmNjYwNyIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NDcyNzg2Mzc5NjksImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; BVBRANDID=b448d567-f852-45f4-b114-784aa3f60b22; scarab.profile=%22000000000000210994%7C1647278780%22; _gcl_aw=GCL.1647291885.Cj0KCQjwz7uRBhDRARIsAFqjulk5bAJN9VM34Mvu46mlftXA-pi6u3ihl_b1WF2cYYGRHiiBqQv-IlMaAiEIEALw_wcB; _gac_UA-36216968-26=1.1647291885.Cj0KCQjwz7uRBhDRARIsAFqjulk5bAJN9VM34Mvu46mlftXA-pi6u3ihl_b1WF2cYYGRHiiBqQv-IlMaAiEIEALw_wcB; _gac_UA-36216968-1=1.1647291892.Cj0KCQjwz7uRBhDRARIsAFqjulk5bAJN9VM34Mvu46mlftXA-pi6u3ihl_b1WF2cYYGRHiiBqQv-IlMaAiEIEALw_wcB; DECLINED_DATE=1647363860132; _ga=GA1.1.1904468361.1647278637; _vis_opt_s=3%7C; kampyleUserSession=1647443910700; kampyleUserSessionsCount=12; kampyleSessionPageCounter=1; kampyleUserPercentile=76.69597099170795; _vwo_ds=3%3Aa_0%2Ct_0%3A0%241647278636%3A14.83535232%3A%3A65_0%2C62_0%3A443_0%2C431_0%2C430_0%2C427_0%2C5_0%2C4_0%3A0; _ga_Z8VQ1XLMKW=GS1.1.1647482462.8.0.1647482462.60; _ga=GA1.2.1904468361.1647278637; _clck=ocen0m|1|ezu|0; _uetvid=87e73510a3bb11ec845961db4a2ee8f4; __cf_bm=Wq7Ri6TwjPflvuTcmaxx_NBGVkBBtewayXNGkF6iRFY-1650921677-0-AenKxR/rPecqs7Ap4M3KUrJz1uWOsVHq8XxTeffRjRC39318w5Y5p5s7+izyRnzL9CxSdTMCKZpgIg1sQoyaPxQ=; cf_chl_2=a1a45f416d52eea; cf_chl_prog=b',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
}

params = {
    'context': 'bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3w3Mzg2MHxpbWFnZS9qcGVnfGltYWdlcy9oM2QvaDk5LzEwNTY3NzE3MDYwNjM4LmpwZ3wwYmJiZjA5MjZkZjNhZTQwMTZiYzdmNTVhM2RmZDhiMTY2ZjI2YzNkY2QzZmUwYmQxNzc5OTY2MTZlNGMxYzBi',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.innovasport.com/medias/IS-DB2455-728-1.jpg', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Comment: Error 403 usually means forbidden. so it mlay requires login, cookies, headers or other auth. methods; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: I doubt you can actually open it in your browser as well :) I've tried to use InPrivate mode in Chrome, and after 2-3 attempts (open InPrivate -> open link -> close InPrivate -> Repeat) I got a 403 & CAPTCHA challenge. So, it looks like that website is using DDoS/scaping protection based on hcaptcha.com that is not that easy to defeat.

Comment: using insomnia, there is indeed a captcha... Maybe selenium libs will work, if CAPTCHA doesn't get always triggered..

Comment: @Je-Je I personally doubt Selenium can help, as I got a CAPTCHA after just a couple attempts from a legit browser. OP can try setting HUGE time delays (which is probably not feasible), or try to understand DDoS configuration and changing headers & IP addresses using proxies etc., or try to look at the problem from a different angle: do they have a mobile app that might contain all info but having less protection? Do they have a mobile website version maybe? Do they have any API that is worth exploring? Anyways, all the above look pretty tough. Good luck to OP - or maybe to website defenders ;)

Comment: @Alex, interesting, captcha didn't trigger on my leggit brother, but only when using insomnia, worth a try, and will need random pause/sleep time.... sometimes depends on IP/location etc...

Comment: @Je-Je I've used InPrivate mode, that was likely the issue :)